# display records with ajax/jquery/json and delete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am displaying records from the database like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'functions/list-articles-delete.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                 $.each(data, function(item){
                    var tr_str = "<tr>"
                    + "<td>" + data[item].n_title + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + data[item].n_dateTime + "</td>"
                    + "<td><button class='btn btn-danger' id='deletebut' data-id='" + data[item].id + "'>Delete</button></td>";
                     $( "#output" ).append(tr_str);

                     $( "#deletebut" ).on('click', function(){
                        // display id of associated record
                }); 
            });         
        },
    });
});
```

When I click on any of the buttons I want it to console.log() the id of the associated record but not quite sure how to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking here? You're already using the ID a couple of rows up? `data[item].id`?

Comment: When I click on the "delete" button, I want it to console.log() the id of that particular record for which the delete button is associated.

Comment: First of, you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`-value. ID's must be _unique_  in a html document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently giving all the buttons the same `id`. In HTML, all `id`'s must be unique.

We can actually remove the id's and just use a class instead. That way, we can register one event that covers all the buttons at the same time.

Here's how I would to this:
(Read the comments for an explanation of the changes)

```
// First, register an event on all the buttons that exists, and 
// might be added, that has the class delete-btn.
// Put this code directly in your document.ready.

$("body").on('click', ".delete-btn", function() {
    // Get the data-id value from the button
    console.log($(this).data('id')); 
}
```

Now, change your loop:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) { // The second argument will get the actual item
    var tr_str = "<tr>"
    + "<td>" + item.n_title + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + item.n_dateTime + "</td>"
    + "<td><button class='btn btn-danger delete-btn' data-id='" + item.id + "'>Delete</button></td>";
     $( "#output" ).append(tr_str);
});
```

Adding the event on the class `.delete-btn` inside the callback will add multiple events on buttons that already exists on the page.

Comment: There are better solutions to this, than creating event on each item. Delegating the event is much cleaner and better.

Comment: @MiKE You're correct. It's enough to just add an event to a class instead.

Comment: This solution looks like the closest to my code that I had and it works nicely. Thanks to all for your assistance!

Comment: @Jonathan I updated it a bit. Making it even better. Registering the event in the ajax callback isn't a good solution since it will add multiple events to the buttons that already existed. The new example solves that.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You are setting the ID on the button with html5 attribute data-id. You use the jquery's data function to access the ID.

```
$( "#deletebut" ).on('click', function(){
    // display id of associated record
    console.log( $(this).data('id') );
});
```

I would also like to point out, that using the same ID in a loop is not a way to go.

You should add a class to the button, e.g. "delete-button".

Then you could delegate the event on the body, which would look like this.

```
$( "body" ).on('click', '.delete-button', function(){
    // display id of associated record
    console.log( $(this).data('id') );
});
```

Using the "this" keyword, you'll be able to fetch the ID of the clicked button, no matter how many there are. And also register this event outside the loop. After or before the loop, but not inside it!

Comment: Don't forget that the OP is actually creating new buttons on each iteration, but adding the same ID to them. Element ID's must be unique in the HTML document.

Comment: If I click on the first button, it logs out the same id number the number of times I have records i.e.: if I have 3 records, it console logs the same id x 3. If I click on any other record's button nothing happens

Comment: Ah, will check it out now

Comment: Yes, that happens because the ID is the same, and jquery finds all of them. Meaning, the registered event will fire all events created.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'.delete-button'` instead of `'delete-button'`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 **var yourID='';**
            $.ajax({
                url: 'functions/list-articles-delete.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                 $.each(data, function(item){
                    **yourID = data[item].n_title;**
                    var tr_str = "<tr>"
                    + "<td>" + data[item].n_title + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + data[item].n_dateTime + "</td>"
                    + "<td><button class='btn btn-danger' id='deletebut' data-id='" + data[item].id + "'>Delete</button></td>";
                     $( "#output" ).append(tr_str);

                     $( "#deletebut" ).on('click', function(){
                        **console.log(yourID);**
                }); 
            });         
        },
    });
});
```